# PayPal recurring payment method

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, recurring

Currently I am using Authorize.net CIM method in my project. Now I want to use paypal for same purpose. I mean it should support one time / recurring payment using payment profile. Which method should I use in paypal?

It should support in below countries...

Czech, Estonia, Greece, Hungary, India,
Indonesia, Malaysia, Philippines, Poland
Romania, Slovenia, Thailand, Turkey,UK

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) with [Recurring Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-recurringPaymentProfile-curl-etc/).